# Automatic generation of numpy slicing in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am porting some code from Fortran to Python, using numpy. The Fortran code handles both two and three dimensional array with a set of macros which are not of interest here. An example of a ported code is given below

```
def computeMatrixElements(M, fcDXidx, ccDXidx, dXi, d, ccregion):

dxscale = 1./(dXi*dXi)
D = len(ccregion.Size())
N=list(ccregion.Size())
N[d]+=1


if D == 3:
    
    M[:,:,:,0] = ccDXidx[:,:,0] * fcDXidx[0:N[0]-ID[d][0],
                                          0:N[1]-ID[d][1],
                                          0:N[2]-ID[d][2],
                                          0] * dxscale
    M[:,:,:,1] = ccDXidx[:,:,0] * fcDXidx[ID[d][0]:N[0], 
                                          ID[d][1]:N[1],
                                          ID[d][2]:N[2],
                                          0] * dxscale
else:
    
    M[:,:,0] = ccDXidx[:,:,0] * fcDXidx[0:N[0]-ID[d][0],
                                        0:N[1]-ID[d][1],
                                        0] * dxscale
    M[:,:,1] = ccDXidx[:,:,0] * fcDXidx[ID[d][0]:N[0], 
                                        ID[d][1]: N[1],
                                        0] * dxscale
```

Note the highly repetitive pattern of the slicing. Having to differentiate the 2D from the 3D case is tedious, not to mention prone to errors. I am wondering if it is possible to automate the process. What I have in mind is something along these lines

```
slice=[]
for dim in range(D):
   slice.append(0)
   slice.append(N[dim]-ID[d][dim])
slice.append(0)
```

and then having some kind way to call fcDXidx[pythonMagic(slice)] so that it resolves to the correct slice.

Comment: Elipsis, `...` can substitute for any number of `:`.  Another option is to expand the dimension of the the small one to the larger, do the work and then 'squeeze' out the excess dimension(s).

Comment: It turns out that using the native slice() function is the way to go.